# jquery Slide toggle parent not child

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
    $('#textButton').click(function() {
        $('#textContainer').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

textButton is a child of textContainer.

Which is a basic tab at the bottom of the page I want to slide up and down when the button is clicked.

Currently clicking once slides it down, and the button does it's own slide away animation so it dispears.

Any way to stop the button sliding away, and sliding the parent container only?

Here is a very rough fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3su2ekjy/1/

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code so that others can check your issue directly and give accurate answer

Comment: Sure, thanks - done http://jsfiddle.net/3su2ekjy/1/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/3su2ekjy/3/

Comment: @user5839 the button is inside the container in your fiddle demo.. so it will automatically disappear when container slideToggle.. place button outside the container

Comment: you can check this code also.. http://jsfiddle.net/3su2ekjy/12/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3su2ekjy/5/)**

If yes so use this JS:

```
$('#textButton').click(function() {
    $('#textContainer #text').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

When you toggle the container it's obvious that all of childrens (include the button) disappear too.

Answer (score 0):

[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) displays or hides the element.

You can not hide the parent without hiding all the parent's children.

So if you must keep the child element visible, you must not have it be a child of the parent element anymore and put it outside of it. Re-arrange your html.